# Graphics2D line and shape drawing issues (rendered in wrong place)

Tags: java, swing, graphics, graphics2d, custom-painting

I've drawn three arrows using Graphics2D.

1. three `drawLine`s
2. `draw(Shape)`
3. `fill(Shape)`

Here's what it looks like enlarged:

[image: drawn arrows]

I cannot understand two things:

1. Why is the filled one smaller and shifted?
2. Secondly, why do arrows 1. and 3. look different? Both consist of 3 antialiased lines. Shouldn't they (potentially) differ only in vertices?

Here's the whole code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class ShapeTest extends JPanel
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(220, 200));
        frame.add(new ShapeTest());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics graphics)
    {
        super.paintComponent(graphics);

        Graphics2D graphics2D = (Graphics2D)graphics;

        graphics.setColor(Color.white);
        graphics.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());

        graphics2D.setColor(Color.black);
        graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        graphics2D.drawLine(100, 40, 103, 46);
        graphics2D.drawLine(103, 46, 106, 40);
        graphics2D.drawLine(100, 40, 106, 40);

        graphics2D.fill(new Polygon(
                new int[]{100, 103, 106},
                new int[]{50, 56, 50},
                3
        ));

        graphics2D.draw(new Polygon(
                new int[]{100, 103, 106},
                new int[]{60, 66, 60},
                3
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: @gpasch Maybe this `setStroke` line is redundant, I'll remove it. I listed everything I want to know. I see no mumbling there.

Comment: A lot comes down to the underlying graphics framework and how they work (DirectX and OpenGL).  When stroking an object, you tend to apply the stroke along the edge of the space, where the stroke will fill evenly either side of it, fill will fill to the inside boundary which can make it smaller.  I would suggest that the two stroked images aren't that different, but are simply using a slightly different algorithm to generate there output

Comment: @MadProgrammer It will be quite intuitive that drawing boundary means drawing 1px-wide line through the middle of edges (ie. 0.5 px to the inside, 0.5 px to the outside), but then both arrows should have the same axis of symmetry. I have already make use of Path2D.Double to make sub-pixel alignment and achieve desired effect, but it would be nice to understand the logic behind.
//edit: as for the second question i would opt for what you said

Comment: @PKua If you want to understand it more, then you will need consult the documentation/source for both DirectX and OpenGL

Comment: @MadProgrammer so this isn't connected that much with Java but more with DirectX/OpenGL?

Comment: @PKua Java/Swing uses a DirectX/OpenGL pipeline to render it's graphics, Java just provides an abstract layer over the two

Comment: @MadProgrammer ok, thanks. So I guess it would be a good idea to check the appearance in different environments.

Comment: This brought me to the right path to solve https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54658008/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems I have found the answers to my question. I post them for other poeple who may face the same problem.

**Smaller**, because, as [MadProgrammer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/992484/madprogrammer) said in a comment below the question, stokes are drawn along the edges through the middle, so a 1px stroke edges will be 0.5px to the each side of the shape edges.

**Shifted** because of rounding. When you draw a line with a float-precision coordinates it can be normalized in some way on some platforms. On Windows, at least for `Path2D.Float` and `Line2D.Float`, it rounds coords to integer numbers. I guess that the same goes for `fill(Shape)`. Fotrunatelly, you can disable stroke normalization by:

```
g2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);
```

It solves the problem:

[image: arrows]

**Different**, because of different rendering algorithms.